# What is the intuition behind the entropy formula used in the ID3 algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, math, decision-trees, id3-algorithm

What is the intuition behind the following entropy formula used in the ID3 algorithm?

$$
\text{info}(D) = -\sum_{i=1}^m p_i \log_2(p_i)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, take a look at [Understanding Shannon's Entropy metric for Information](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1405/1405.2061.pdf).

The answer for the minus sign is in section 6. The probability logs are less than or equal to $0$, so the minus sign guarantees that information (entropy) is always greater than or equal to $0$.